# HTML page waiting for server response before loading

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, rest

I'm trying to develop a website with user registration/login that connects with a database for authentication.
I would like for my HTML pages to wait a little before loading so I can redirect the client to the proper page, i.e. if the user logged in recently we can skip the login page and go straight to the app page; if the user has not logged in yet and tries to access the app page he is redirected to the login page).

Currently I have the following JS code in my app page:

```
window.onload = function() {
if(localStorage.tokenID == null || !authenticateToken(localStorage.tokenID)) {
    window.location.replace("login.html");
    ...
}
```

where authenticateToken(tokenID) is a method that sends a REST request to my server and returns a boolean that indicates whether the token is valid or not.

Not this works well apart from the issue that the page starts loading while waiting for the server reply and then suddenly changes.

Is there a way to make the HTML loading wait for the server reply before starting to load anything at all?

Comment: You can put loader or show white screen untill server response back.

Comment: Your answer will depend on how authenticateToken works. Your issue is that it is running asynchronously and you are not waiting for a response. You will either need to make it run synchronously (bad) or redirect after it completes using what ever is available. Usually this is done with either a callback or a promise.